# There is something strange with the c++ "delete" command

Tags: c++, pointers

If deleting the pointer, why is the output 5 5?(I'm new)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int* i = new int(5);

    cout<< *i <<endl;
    delete i;
    cout<< *i <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not strange. `delete` simply deallocates the memory. It doesn't clear out that memory region. Hence you can see the contents of that memory location being retained until some other part of your program rewrites it. You can read more about `delete` keyword [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/).

Comment: The second `cout<< *i <<endl;` is **undefined behavior** because it is dereferencing a dangling pointer.  Undefined behavior means that it may do something strange, or it may crash, or it may send your browser history to your grandmother, or it may rouse Cthulhu from his slumber in the sunken lost city of R'lyeh, or worse... it may appear to still work.

Comment: Argon's answer was enough. Thanks.

Comment: You can accept the answer to mark your question as solved. This is done by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete doesn't set 0 or any value to the memory `i` is pointing to. It just flags it as free so something can use it later. This leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)